# More than one software centre

Tags: software-installation, software-center

I'm sorry this is a bit long but reading the first and last paragraphs below should give you an idea of what I am asking... the middle is just my justification for asking and can be skipped.

In Ubuntu 20.04 there were somewhat confusingly two software centers. There was the 'Ubuntu Software Center' (the orange one that appeared on the task bar after installation) and then there was the 'Software Center' (The blue and white one that was installed less prominently among the other apps).

I always thought this was kind of a bizarre set up as both appeared nearly identical... BUT IMPORTANTLY AND CRITICALLY they weren't!

I notice the second one of these has disappeared in 22.04 and I feel it is a sensible move to amalgamate them... however, they have NOT been amalgamated, we have just lost one!

The reason this is important is because the second of these two software centers gave access to slightly different software, often containing older versions of programs and THIS is important for two reasons:

1. Because some older versions of programs do things newer ones can't (for example Inkscape's devs deliberately broke their extensions for anyone using vital older extensions that are no longer under development and thus, not available in their newer extension style) and...
2. Because many of the newer app versions don't actually seem to run (Arduino IDE being just one example)...yes... I've found the fix but all the same *shrugs*... and there are others.

I ABSOLUTELY CANNOT live my life without Inkscape 0.92.5 and can find no other way to install it that is successful other than the blue and white software center which I now don't have. I've tried about 5 other ways. Either dependencies cannot be met or it just doesn't work or the wrong version is installed despite claims to the contrary by Inkscape.org. I've spent 3 days of my life on it and I'm very tired of fighting to have something I once had back.

My questions therefore are:

1. What enabled the blue and white software center to access this other selection of software? What was different about it?
2. Can this blue and white software center be added to 22.04? (I cannot find a way).
3. If not, how do I gain access to these vital pieces of older software without reverting back to 20.04?

Comment: If your question is really about how to install the old verson of Inkscape, please make that your question.

Comment: @Organic Marble That is not my question. There are other apps only available from the blue and white software center which are important also. If you have an alternate way to effectively install Inkscape 0.92.5 though, please, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not just install it from Inkscape's official website? https://inkscape.org/release/inkscape-0.92.5/